# Dynamic WCF Service Contracts based on authentication credentials

Tags: wcf

1) I want to have Client Application that adds a reference to a WCF service

2) The Client Application should be able to send credentials to this WCF service

3) Based on credentials permissions, WCF service should return appropriate Interface (service contract) to client

4) Client then consumes it.

e.g. suppose i hav a Class at Server, which defines an entity say 'Asset' and have some methods related to all possible operations over it

```
Class Asset
{
 Add()
 {
 .....
 }

 Edit()
 {
 ......
 }

 Flag()
 {
 ......
 }

 Deploy()
 {
 ........
 }
}
```

Now i have Client application that wants to perform some actions on 'Asset'. But i don't want to give the entire class DLL to client. Instead want to give only interface. which client can consume and call appropriate actions over it.

Now the problem is when client app adds reference to a WCF service. How can appropriate interface for Asset class be returned to client based on its WS* or authentication credentials. Does .Net 4.0 provides any easy way to create and return a service contract dynamically?

e.g.

```
//following is pseudo code
If(Current.User.Role == 'Admin')
{
 return IAssetsForAdmin;
}
else
{
 return IAssetsForGeneralUser;
}

Interface IAssetForAdmin
{
 Add();
 Edit();
 Flag();
}

Interface IAssetForGeneralUser
{
 Flag();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You can't return different contract per user role. Moreover it is not only related to WCF but to whole web services architecture and .NET architecture because defining new contract = defining new service reference = recompiling application.

But this can be easily solved by role based security. Authenticated user will be member of some role which will be allowed to execute only selected operations. To achieve this you cau use PrincipalPermission (for imperative demand of permissions) or PrincipalPermissionAttribute (for declarative demand of permissions). If unauthorized user calls secured method SecurityException will be thrown. The only thing you need is properly configure WCF security model so that roles are assigned to authenticated users.